# The volume of boundary layer

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, geometric-measure-theory

Let $\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^3$ be an open bounded set with $C^2$ boundary $\partial\Omega$. Let $\operatorname{d}(x):=\inf_{y\in\partial\Omega}|x-y|$ for $x\in\overline{\Omega}$, and the open set $\Omega_h:=\{x\in\Omega;\operatorname{d}(x)<h\}$. Are there estimates about the volume of $\Omega_h\setminus\Omega_{h/2}$?

Comment: It's probably difficult to find a useful bound when $h$ is `large'. Would you be happy to impose $h$ small (in terms of $\partial \Omega$)? In that case I wouldn't see any issue with obtaining an estimate of the form $c h \leq \mathrm{Vol} \, ( \Omega_h \setminus \Omega_{h/2}) \leq C h$ with constants $c, C > 0$ depending on $\Omega$.

Comment: @Leo Moos Yup. Actually, I need the estimate $\operatorname{Vol}(\Omega_h\setminus\Omega_{h/2})\le Ch$ for $h$ small enough.